# Apache2 won't start due to locate-error

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-perl, sles10

I am running Apache/2.2.9 on SLES 10 and want to use [Apache2::REST](http://search.cpan.org/~jeteve/Apache2-REST-0.07/lib/Apache2/REST.pm).

I installed it using cpan and added the Handler and the configuration stuff.
When I try to start Apache (apache2ctl start), it says:

> [Thu Sep 01 11:13:30 2011] [warn] module apreq_module is already loaded, skipping
>
> [Thu Sep 01 11:13:30 2011] [warn] module perl_module is already loaded, skipping

The error.log tells me:

> [Thu Sep 01 10:43:06 2011] [error] Can't locate Apache2/Request.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
>   /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl 
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl . /etc/apache2) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Apache2/REST.pm line 8.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Apache2/REST.pm line 8.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 5) line 3.\n
>
> [Thu Sep 01 10:43:06 2011] [error] Can't load Perl module Apache2::REST for server servername:0, exiting...

I get the same error on SLES 10. But there I cannot even install apreq2.

Comment: It means that the `Apache2::REST` module is not installed properly. Check with `instmodsh` or `$ perl -MApache2::REST -e "print \"Module installed\\n\";"`.

Comment: instmodsh finds the following modules:    Apache2::REST
   Class::AutoAccess
   ExtUtils::MakeMaker
   ExtUtils::XSBuilder
   JSON::XS
   Perl
   YAML
   common::sense
...
$ perl -MApache2::REST -e "print \"Module installed\\n\";"
still says "Can't locate Apache2/Request.pm in @INC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you need to install libapreq2 That, or the existing installation is corrupted.
The ''already loaded'' messages are immaterial.

Comment: C'est ça. The installation was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

> locate Request.pm

and check if it finds anything.

Otherwise, check what files are provided by the installed package

Comment: `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Apache2/REST/Request.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/HTTP/Request.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Apache2-REST-0.07/lib/Apache2/REST/Request.pm
/root/.cpan/build/Apache2-REST-0.07/blib/lib/Apache2/REST/Request.pm
/root/.cpan/build/libapreq2-2.13/glue/perl/lib/Apache2/Request.pm
/root/.cpan/build/libapreq2-2.13/glue/perl/xsbuilder/APR/Request/Request.pm
`

It seems to be in a cpan-folder but not in really installed?!

Comment: when i start cpan and type in "install Apache2::Request" there is a lot of gcc stuff and in the end it says: ##################make[2]: *** [libapreq2.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/libapreq2-2.13/library'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/libapreq2-2.13/library'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  /usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

Comment: Ok ... maybe you add add site_perl and vendor_perl to INC. Are you trying to compile it as root ?